# Notepad++ plugin - How to add coffeescripts plugin

Tags: plugins, coffeescript, notepad++

I'm trying to add coffeescripts plug in to notepadd++. I found the plugin from [here](https://github.com/blakmatrix/CoffeeScript_notepad_UDL). There is no `.dll` file in the zip file i downloaded from the link above. When I read the ReadMeFile, it says.

```
# CoffeeScript syntax highlighting for Notepad++
***


Will syntax highlight files with extensions of coffee, coco, and CAKEFILE using Notepad++'s user-defined language(within its limits).


![An example Screenshot](/blakmatrix/CoffeeScript_notepad_UDL/raw/master/example_screenshot.png)


## Deployment


1. If you don't have an userDefineLang.xml file already, you can drop this file among your other configuration file, in the Notepad++ Install Folder. It should be named userDefineLang.xml.
2. Otherwise, open both the existing and new file.
    - Select all of the new file, copy, and paste at the end of the current file.
    - This should have created a spurious </Notepad_Plus><Notepad_plus> pair in the middle, each tag on a line by itself. Remove these two consecutive lines.
    - Close Notepad++.


Your Languages menu should show the newly added language at the bottom, next time you launch Notepad++.


***
### Contact
Contact me at blakmatrix@gmail.com for any questions or tips!
```

Can anyone help me to install the plugin. Didnt understand what the readme saying.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into a similar issue. My solution with Notepad v6.3.3 (may not be optimal):

1. Download the CoffeeScript.xml from that Git repo. Make sure you unzip it if it is zipped.
2. Open up Notepad++. Under the Languages menu, select "Define your language..."
3. At the top, click the Import button. Navigate to the CoffeeScript.xml, select it, and select Open. Press the x in the top-right corner of the dialog to close it.
4. Restart Notepad++. You should see CoffeeScript at the bottom of the Languages menu. Any .coffee files you now open should have syntax coloring.